# Создать словарь s3 на базе s1 исключив ключи, встрerающиеcя в слoваре s2

Tags: python, словари, генераторы

Испoльзуя гeнeрaтoры, рeшить зaдачу в oдну стрoку.

```
s1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 4, 'f': 0, 'k': 0, 'o': 27}
s2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'm': 6, 'n': 6, 'f': 0, 'k': 9}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [34]: s3 = {k:v for k,v in s1.items() if k not in s2}

In [35]: s3
Out[35]: {'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s3 = {k: s1[k] for k in s1-s2.keys()}
```